# Django __str()__ method for model based on other instances

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, assuming a model that has a date and a description as attributes:

```
2021 Feb 04 Description A
2021 Feb 02 Description B
2021 Jan 31 Description C
2021 Jan 30 Description D
2020 Dec 24 Description E
```

Is there an easy way to *not* print the year/month if there is an older record with that year/month?

```
         04 Description A
     Feb 02 Description B
         31 Description C
2021 Jan 30 Description D
         24 Description E
```

Can I write a `__str()__` or another method for that model that considers others instances of the model? I have been through Meta options for models in Django but I'm not sure to which extent I can customize those.

Comment: str() is simply a string representation of the model object.Is there an easy way to not print the year/month? Explain this more .. Where are we intending on displaying this data

Comment: Shouldn't you have such logic in your views or templates. Although it is possible most likely you want to use it for a template which already has these other instances. What happens when you want a string representation of an instance without these other instances?